# different screen sizes with the same width dp

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm confused with different screen sizes support in android. Assume we have *phone1* with for example **1000*500 pixels** and *phone2*  **2000*1000 pixels** and pixel density of both is  **xhdpi(320)**  (phone2 has less quality). well if i define a layout for `xhdpi` `(res/drawable-xhdpi)`, which one of these phones will target the xhdpi layout? if both of them, there would be a problem here, the max width of phone1 is 250dp (500/2) and the max width of phone2 is 500dp (1000/2) and how can i set some object the for example in the middle of the activity. for phone1 would be 125dp and for phone2 would be 250dp? am i right?

Comment: if you want to use any view in the middle(i believe you are talking about center), why don;t you use xml attributes of parent layout(ViewGroup like linear layout, constrait layout etc)?

Comment: Use constraint layout, it is designed to solve such problems.

Comment: setting in the middle is an example. i want to say that there is no standard way for me to position theses objects because of different width in dp in both phones

Comment: assume i want to setup an animation. i need to specify the start and end animation width in dp and it cause problem

Answer (score 2):

You are right that android developers have little troubles with a lot of variety of screen densities, so it is the main reason why you should use dp or sp values instead of px values. Also you can use special layouts (e.g. RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout) for positioning your views in the context of other views on layout or parent container itself.

In your case (you need to centralize view) you might use a couple of the existing layouts if they allow you to set rules for positioning in the layout-center and regardless of screen size and density existing view will be at the center of the layout.

Also check out [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support)

Comment: setting in the middle is an example. i want to say that there is no standard way for me to position theses objects because of different width in dp in both phones. assume i want to setup an animation. i need to specify the start and end animation width in dp and it cause problem

Comment: Yes, you're right. It'll cause problems but the right way which you can follow is using concrete values as less as you can and trying to use relative values and relative ties such as (bounds, constraints etc.). Device-independent pixels pretty good but there is no silver bullet ;(

Answer (score 0):

Centering images can be done using [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) with parameters like this:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Keeping the same margin/padding you can either use simple weights in [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

```
android:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
```

or if you are not satisfy you can set proper value using [SDP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) library

```
android:margin="@dimen/_27sdp"
```